# GetMonitorBrightness() crashes with Access Violation

Tags: c++, winapi, screen-brightness

I'm trying to set up a small programm to adjust Monitor Brightness by the current room brightness.

I followed the instructions from MSDN and set up this:

```
cout << "Legen Sie das Fenster bitte auf den zu steuernden Monitor.\n";
system("PAUSE");
HMONITOR hMon = NULL;
char OldConsoleTitle[1024];
char NewConsoleTitle[1024];
GetConsoleTitle(OldConsoleTitle, 1024);
SetConsoleTitle("CMDWindow7355608");
Sleep(40);
HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "CMDWindow7355608");
SetConsoleTitle(OldConsoleTitle);
hMon = MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);


DWORD cPhysicalMonitors;
LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR pPhysicalMonitors = NULL;
BOOL bSuccess = GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(
    hMon,
    &cPhysicalMonitors
    );

if(bSuccess)
{
    pPhysicalMonitors = (LPPHYSICAL_MONITOR)malloc(
        cPhysicalMonitors* sizeof(PHYSICAL_MONITOR));

    if(pPhysicalMonitors!=NULL)
    {
        LPDWORD min = NULL, max = NULL, current = NULL;
        GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMon, cPhysicalMonitors, pPhysicalMonitors);

        HANDLE pmh = pPhysicalMonitors[0].hPhysicalMonitor;

        if(!GetMonitorBrightness(pmh, min, current, max))
        {
            cout << "Fehler: " << GetLastError() << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            return 0;
        }

        //cout << "Minimum: " << min << endl << "Aktuell: " << current << endl << "Maximum: " << max << endl;

        system("PAUSE");
    }

}
```

But the problem: everytime I try to use GetMonitorBrightness() the program crashes with `Access Violation while writing at Position 0x00000000` (I translated this error from German)

While trying to debug I saw that pPhysicalMonitors actually contains the monitor I want to use, but `pPhysicalMonitors[0].hPhysicalMonitor` contains 0x0000000 only. Could this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> everytime I try to use GetMonitorBrightness() the program crashes with Access Violation while writing at Position 0x00000000 (I translated this error from German)

You are passing NULL pointers to `GetMonitorBrightness()`, so it crashes when trying to write its output values to invalid memory.

Just like `GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR()`, `GetMonitorBrightness()` expects you to pass the address of actual variables, eg:

```
DWORD min, max, current;
if (!GetMonitorBrightness(pmh, &min, &current, &max))
```

> While trying to debug I saw that pPhysicalMonitors actually contains the monitor I want to use, but pPhysicalMonitors[0].hPhysicalMonitor contains 0x0000000 only. Could this be part of the problem?

No.  However, you are not checking to make sure that `cPhysicalMonitors` is > 0, and you are ignoring the return value of `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR()` to make sure it is actually populating the `PHYSICAL_MONITOR` array with data.

Comment: Thank you very much, the DWORD and addresses fixed it.